# Error when try to use dialog in fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, dialog, fullcalendar

i'm trying to use dialog as a form, to put event in my database with ajax.

My code the "select:" element :

```
select: function(start, end, allDay) {
                var title  = $('#title');
                var agenda = $('#agenda');
                var boite  = $("#dialog-form").dialog({
                    autoOpen: false,
                    height: 200,
                    width: 500,
                    buttons: {
                        "Creer le nouvel evenement": function() {
                            $.ajax({
                                url: "{{ path('event_add') }}",
                                type: "POST",
                                data: { start: start, end: end, allday: allDay, title: title, agenda: agenda }
                            })
                            .done(function() {
                                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                            });
                        }
                    },
                    Cancel: function() {
                        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                    },
                    close: function() {
                    }
                });
                if (boite.dialog("open")) {
                    calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent',
                    {
                        title: title,
                        start: start,
                        end: end,
                        allDay: allDay
                    },
                    true // make the event "stick"
                    );
                }
                calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
    },
```

There is two situation :

- First situation : 
  I try with the jquery file found in fullcalendar folder, the dialog don't appears and i get that error :

> TypeError: $(...).dialog is not a function

- Second situation :
  I try with the last jquery files, the dialog appears but i get 2 errors :

> TypeError: s.replace is not a function (fullcalendar line 1837)
>   TypeError: 'stepUp' called on an object that does not implement interface HTMLInputElement. (jquery1.9.1 line 7340)

The s.replace error appear when i click on a day to get the dialog.
The stepUp error appear when i click on the button inside the dialog.

Any solution ?

Thx in advance :)

PS : Sorry for my english, i'm not a natural english speaker.

Comment: Did you include `jquery-ui`?

Comment: Yes, i include jquery1.9.1 and jquery-ui 1.10.4

Comment: Can you provide a simple demo on jsfiddle?